# GSCAM over ubuntu server

Tags: gscam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all..

i'm trying to add a web cam to my pionner at-e robot, i have ubuntu 10.4 server version (no x systems), i have already installed the required components of GSCAM and the compilation gives no errors or warnings

i export the environment variable

$ export GSCAM_CONFIG="v4l2src device=/dev/video1 ! video/x-raw-rgb ! ffmpegcolorspace"

then i run the node

$ rosrun gscam gscam

but i get the next error:

Gstreamer Version: GStreamer 0.10.28
no element "v4l2src"

any ideas? is it possible to run gscam on a server edition of ubuntu?

thanks a lot

Mario

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/28191/gscam-over-ubuntu-server/) by [Mario Garzon](https://answers.ros.org/users/568/mario-garzon/) on ROS Answers with karma: 802 on 2012-02-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to have the gstreamer0.10-plugins-good package installed. The v4l2src element is located in the "good" plugins http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-good-plugins/html/gst-plugins-good-plugins-v4l2src.html

---

Originally posted by [John Hoare](https://answers.ros.org/users/159/john-hoare/) with karma: 765 on 2012-02-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mario Garzon](https://answers.ros.org/users/568/mario-garzon/) on 2012-02-22**:
Thanks a lot... that solved my the problem... i had installed only the gstreamer0.10-plugins :)